# Render Image on a template from a json string [Wagtail CMS]

Tags: python, django, content-management-system, wagtail

I have the below output:

```
{'type': 'lead-image', 'value': {'id': 123, 'alt': 'a fish', 'format': 'full-width'}}
```

I want to display that specific image on my html template, how do i go about it?

Comment: Have posted a direct answer, but I'm kind of curious how this scenario has come up, and where this data comes from... are you doing some sort of rich-text to StreamField conversion?

Comment: hi gasman share the email is end you the code thanks alot for your input to

Answer (score 1):

The `expand_db_attributes` method on `wagtail.wagtailimages.rich_text.ImageEmbedHandler` does the translation you're looking for. Packaged up as a template tag (please adjust as appropriate for your own use-case - it looks like you've got a Python dict there, rather than a JSON string):

```
import json
from django.utils.html import escape
from wagtail.wagtailimages.rich_text import ImageEmbedHandler


register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag
def json_to_image(json_string):
    data = json.loads(json_string)

    # expand_db_attributes expects to receive HTML-escaped attributes,
    # so explicitly escape the alt attribute here (assuming it's not already
    # escaped in your json)
    data['value']['alt'] = escape(data['value']['alt'])

    return ImageEmbedHandler.expand_db_attributes(data['value'], False)
```

Comment: what if i dont have the alt attribute and all i have is the id and caption?